# Biblatex @misc show institution

Tags: biblatex

I using biblatex and Citavi. Citavi puts out for alot of the items a @misc entry. I need the instituion shown in the bibliography. How to get this done?
I use:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,url=false,style=numeric]{biblatex}
```

The mimal exampele:

```
    \documentclass[ captions=tableheading, chapterprefix, BCOR=4mm, cdfont=false]{tudscrreprt}      % parskip > unbekannte Bedeutung, twoside > duplex 
%====================================== Basics ==============================================================================

\usepackage[german]{varioref}               % ermöglicht Verweise mit Seitenzahl
\pdfminorversion=7                          % PDF 1.7
\usepackage{setspace}                       % line spacing                  Effekt nochmal Testen!
\onehalfspacing                             % onehalfspacing
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % European  encoding

\usepackage{csquotes}               % Zitierstil
\usepackage[backend=biber,url=false,style=numeric]{biblatex} %style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear ,style=numeric
\addbibresource{tes.bib}        % Bibtex Quelle

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                                 % new German  spelling rules for automatic elements  

\begin{document}
test
\cite{Streuber.2013}

    \appendix
    \printbibliography%[title=Quellen]
\end{document}
```

And the .bib

```
@misc{Streuber.2013,
author = {Bonn, Werner and Eißler, Werner and Rusche, Stefan and Streuber, Christian},
date = {2013},
title = {Formelsammlung für die Lehrveranstaltungen Wärmelehre, Strömungslehre und Wärmeübertragung},
edition = {5. Auflage},
institution = {{Hochschule RheinMain}}}
```

Comment: What about changing the type to `report`?

Comment: Have you considered using the `@manual` entry type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look at the `biblatex` documentation shows that `@misc` supports

[image: A fallback type for entries which do not fit into any other category. Use the field howpublished to supply publishing information in free format, if applicable. The field type may be useful as well. author, editor, and year are omissible in terms of § 2.3.2. Required fields: author/editor, title, year/date Optional fields: subtitle, titleaddon, language, howpublished, type, version, note, organization, location, month, addendum, pubstate, doi, eprint, eprintclass, eprinttype, url, urldate]

So `institution` is silently ignored.

However, the field `organization` is functionally equivalent. So I suggest you use that.

Most types support one of the functionally equivalent (list) fields `publisher`, `organization` and `institution`. So if things don't come out as you'd hoped, play around with those three terms and usually you can get what you want.

```
\documentclass{tudscrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, url=false,]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Streuber.2013,
  author       = {Bonn, Werner and Eißler, Werner and Rusche, Stefan
                  and Streuber, Christian},
  date         = {2013},
  title        = {Formelsammlung für die Lehrveranstaltungen
                  Wärmelehre, Strömungslehre und Wärmeübertragung},
  edition      = {5},
  organization = {Hochschule RheinMain},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite{Streuber.2013}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Werner Bonn u.a. Formelsammlung für die Lehrveranstaltungen Wärmelehre, Strömungslehre und Wärmeübertragung. Hochschule RheinMain, 2013.]

You could also look into using a different entry type. As you can see, `@misc` drops the `edition` field as well, so that piece of information is hidden.

`@booklet` doesn't have an `edition` field either, so it is probably not that useful.

I don't think I would use `@report` here, because that is usually used for research reports, discussion papers etc. and a formula handbook feels slightly different, but that I just my gut instinct. But you could use the `version` field instead of `edition`.

`@manual` as mentioned [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619902/biblatex-misc-show-institution/619938#comment1547846_619902) by [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) is an option, but then you might as well just use `@book` (which does not have an `organization`, but a `publisher`).

```
\documentclass{tudscrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, url=false,]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Streuber.2013,
  author       = {Bonn, Werner and Eißler, Werner and Rusche, Stefan
                  and Streuber, Christian},
  date         = {2013},
  title        = {Formelsammlung für die Lehrveranstaltungen
                  Wärmelehre, Strömungslehre und Wärmeübertragung},
  edition      = {5},
  publisher    = {Hochschule RheinMain},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite{Streuber.2013}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Werner Bonn u.a. Formelsammlung für die Lehrveranstaltungen Wärmelehre, Strömungslehre und Wärmeübertragung. 5. Aufl. Hochschule RheinMain, 2013.]